# Sails.js hook for csrf protection showing strange behaviour when calling from a chrome app like Postman

Tags: csrf, sails.js

I am performing a post via Postman on my restful API written in sails.js. CSRF flag is enabled in the crfs.js config file. The post is performed without valid csrf token but is working which is surprising me.

In this case the req.headers.origin is filled in and the origin looks like chrome-extension://... As the isSameOrigin function is verifying against http(s) this give no matches back so the result is false and no csrf token verification is done.

Could the code

```
if (sails.config.csrf && (!req.headers.origin || util.isSameOrigin(req)))
```

be replaced by

```
if (sails.config.csrf)
```

Next to this I would like to know what is the best thing to do within a single page app with calls to the REST API. Is it necessary to ask for a csrfToken on each single call or can the same csrfToken be used as long as the session is valid. Which one is the best practice ? The tokens requested seem to remain valid as long as the session is valid.

Highly appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF attacks aren't a concern for requests where the Origin header is sent, or when the origin is on the same site.  They're only a concern when you're getting a request from an unknown location (like a form POST without a *referrer* header) which sends cookies along with it without the sender really thinking about it.  When you're using Postman, you only have access to your own cookies, so there's no danger of being able to pose as someone else.  Thus, CSRF  isn't really necessary.  It may be possible to turn off the Origin header coming out of Postman, if you really want to test your CSRF protection; you'd have to look at the docs.

As far as single-page Sails apps go, the CSRF token is valid for the length of the session, so you only need to request the token once.  The chances of someone guessing the token are slim! (that's the point).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Scott. I think the idea of having CSRF is to have an additional check when someone could have intercepted your session cookie and wants to use it for making its own requests using another ones authentication. This would not be possible without having the CSRF header attached to the request. So in the case with Postman I suppose that a person who intercepts the cookie will be able to do the request without the CSRF check. Maybe I am missing something but I thought this was the reason to use CSRF ?

Comment: Not exactly. A CSRF attack occurs when a malicious website tricks the user into making a request to another site with which they are already authenticated; the attacker never actually steals the user's session. See the [wikipedia entry](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) for the classic "bank withdrawal via image tag" example. If a user's session is actually *hijacked*, so that the *attacker* can make requests as the user, then a CSRF token won't help.

Comment: Also, re: replacing the code you mentioned in your question--that would break the blueprint actions which are a pretty handy part of Sails!

Comment: Thanks Scott for the additional feedback.